# Align text to the center onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking to create a simple text editor for my website, and I want to make a button that on click, aligns text to the center. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use to jquery and a button click to button assign to CSS `text-align` center as like this .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('.btncenter').on('click', function(){
    $('#cenerText').css({'text-align':'center'});
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cenerText">Write some text here </div>

<button class="btncenter">Click here for text align center about div section </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to enter text, add it to the page and center it:

```js
$('.add').on('click', function(){
  var text = $('textarea').val();
  
  $('p').html(text);
});

$('.center').on('click', function(){  
  var centered = document.createElement('center');
  centered.appendChild($('p')[0]);
  $('body').append(centered);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>

<button class='add'>
  enter text
</button>
<button class='center'>
  center
</button>

<p>
  
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS style on click event. Try this. Hope it will help.

```js
/*Java Script */
    function doCenter(){    
        document.getElementById("my_text").style.textAlign="center";
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     
     <!-- Buttons -->
     <input type="button" value="Center" onclick="doCenter()"/>
     <br />
     
     <!-- Text area -->
     <textarea class="text_edit" id="my_text"></textarea>
     <br />
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This definitely did help, thanks! However, now the issue is that everything inside my editor is centralized - any way to make only the highlighted text centralized?